# Need a event when we hide columns while using showColumnMenu

Tags: angular-ui, ng-grid

i am using showColumnMenu=true; in my grid options to filter columns in the grid. When i uncheck a column(ie., hide a column see image) i want a event to be triggered i went through gridEvents i found a event ngGridEventColumns which fires once. ie., if i uncheck any column it fires if i check again or uncheck any other column it does not fire. Is there any event or any work around so that a event is fired every time columns are checked or unchecked in the columnMeny filter[image]